# Execute js after arriving at new page

Tags: javascript, jquery

How would I execute some javascript **upon** arriving at a new page? For example, click a link a new page loads and then some script is executed on that new page?

EDIT: The problem is that I only want the js to execute when you're **arriving there from a certain page** so dom ready code on that destination page would fire any time that page is loaded.

Comment: how about "$(document).on("pagecontainerload",function(){
  alert("pagecontainerload event fired!");
});"

Comment: is your problem solved @Kirk Ross? if yes don't forget to validate the answer. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Just define your function at the end of your page `body` or in your `<head>`:

```
<script> myFunction(){
            //some code here
         }
</script>
```

And the set the `onload` on your page body to run that function:

```
<body onload="myFunction()">
```

This is the **Javascript** method. For jQuery, use `$(document).ready()`.

Comment: The problem is that I only want the js to execute when you're coming from a certain page, and dom ready code would fire any time that page is loaded. I'll modify my OP.

Comment: See my EDIT in my OP.

Answer (score 1):

**with Jquery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    //The code here is executed after the page is loaded

})
```

**with Javascript**

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
  //The code here is executed after the page is loaded
});
```